# Converting an SPI configuration for msp430 to msp432 IAR Workbench

Tags: spi, dac, msp430, iar

I have a spi configuration code for a `msp430` and `DAC161S997` but i am trying to use the DAC with my `msp-exp432p4111`. One of the register has complately different use on msp432. So i couldnt figure it out. Here is my code

```
 EUSCI_B_CMSIS(EUSCI_B0_BASE)->BRW = 48000000 / 1000000;
```

and msp430 code

```
UCB0BR0 = 8;         // SMCLK/8 = SCLK (1MHz)
UCB0BR1 = 0;
```

[Datasheet for DAC](http://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/dac161s997)
[msp432p411 datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/msp432p4111)

Comment: Draw out each of the  command bytes and explain what each bit field does.

Comment: I have removed unnecessary codes

Comment: Ok to get this clear, you have an arm micro controller and you are trying to set it up to drive an SPI DAC?

Comment: yes, i am but having problems with spi config.

Comment: Have you got an oscilloscope? Try a slow baud rate to begin with.